# ProgrammingError: relation does not exist при создании пользователя

Tags: python, django

## models.py

```
from django.db import models
 from django.contrib.auth.models import BaseUserManager, AbstractBaseUser

class MyUserManager(BaseUserManager):
def create_user(self, email, dob, password = None):
    user = self.model(
        email = self.normalize_email(email),
        dob = dob
        )
    user.set_password(password)
    user.save(using=self._db)

    return user

def create_superuser(self, email, dob, password):
    suser = self.create_user(email, password=password, dob=dob)
    suser.is_admin = True
    suser.save(using=self._db)
    return suser

class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):
email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
dob = models.DateField()
is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

objects = MyUserManager()

USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
REQUIRED_FIELD = ['dob']

@property
def is_staff(self):
    return self._is_staff
```

## admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group

from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import ReadOnlyPasswordHashField


from .models import MyUser

class UserCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

class Meta:
    model = MyUser
    fields = ('email', 'dob')

def save(self, commit=True):
    user = super(UserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)

    user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
    if commit:
        user.save()
    return user

class UserChangeForm(forms.ModelForm):
password = ReadOnlyPasswordHashField

class Meta:
    model = MyUser
    fields = ('email', 'password', 'dob', 'is_active', 'is_admin')

def clean_password(self):
    return self.initial["password"]

class MyAdmin(UserAdmin):
form = UserChangeForm ##
add_form = UserCreationForm

list_display = ('email', 'dob', 'is_admin')
list_filter =  ('is_admin',)
fieldsets = (
    (None, {'fields': ('email', 'password',)}),
    ('Personal info', {'fields': ('dob',)}),
    ('Permisions', {'fields': ('is_admin',)}),
    )

add_fieldsets = (
    (None, {
        'classes': ('wide',),
        'fields': ('email','dob', 'password1', 'password2')
        }
    )
)


search_fields = ('email',)
ordering = ('email',)
filter_horizontal = ()

 admin.site.register(MyUser, MyAdmin)
 admin.site.unregister(Group)
```

## settings.py

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'client.MyUser'
```

Пытаюсь создать суперпользователя командой `python manage.py createsuperuser` - выдает ошибку:

> ProgrammingError: relation "client_myuser" does not exist

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
python manage.py syncdb
```

На `syncdb` выдает ошибку:

> ProgrammingError: relation "client_myuser" does not exist

Код брал с http://djangoproject.com.

Где и в чем ошибка?

Comment: already exists или does not exist?

Comment: does not exist. Ошибки копировал из терминала

Answer (score 1):

Изменять базовую модель юзера в Django - плохая идея, это не тот уровень логики, с которым должен взаимодействовать Enterprise разработчик. Там же на djangoproject написано:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model

> Warning
>
> Changing AUTH_USER_MODEL has a big effect on your database structure. It changes the tables that are available, and it will affect the construction of foreign keys and many-to-many relationships. If you intend to set AUTH_USER_MODEL, you should set it before creating any migrations or running manage.py migrate for the first time.
>
> Changing this setting after you have tables created is not supported by makemigrations and will result in you having to manually fix your schema, port your data from the old user table, and possibly manually reapply some migrations.

Чтобы это заработало нужно в каждой связанной с моделью User моделью пересоздать связь. И даже если вам удастся всё это сделать, это будет мина замедленного действия. Ведь мы в Django подключаем десятки сторонних приложений, некоторые из которых взаимодействуют с моделью пользователя, и зачастую напрямую обращаются к

`from django.contrib.auth.models import User`

а если и используют описанное в документации AUTH_USER_MODEL то ожидают от него стандартного поведения. Так что конфликты неизбежны, зачем усложнять себе жизнь?

Хорошей практикой будет расширение модели пользователя через OneToOne модель https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model
Дополнительные поля - сколько угодно. Дополнительная валидация - методы clear. Нужна авторизация при помощи e-mail? на здоровье, просто переопределити метод login для своего приложения авторизации (есть и готовые расширения)

Кроме того - это будет правильно с точки зрения оптимизации структуры БД. Для проверки прав, авторизации, и прочего достаточно базовой модели User, и только в контексте взаимодействия с пользователем нужна дополнительная модель (как правило профиль пользователя).